# if all the brackets are matched in the string I should print bracket matched

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, loops

- I am new to JavaScript.
- I am trying to write logic such that, if all the brackets are matched in a string of only brackets, there should be `bracket matched` printed if all brackets match or `bracket not matched` if the brackets do not match.

```
var bracketString = "((()()()))";
var match = true;

for (i = 0; i < bracketString.length; i++) {

        if (bracketString[i] === "(" && bracketString[i+1] === ")" ) {
            i++;
        } else if (bracketString[i] != "(" && bracketString[i+1] == ")" ) {
            i++;
        } else {
            i++;
            match = false;
        }

}

match ? console.log('Brackets matched') : console.log('Brackets not matched');
```

Comment: Can the string **only** contain `(` and `)`? Nothing else?

Answer (score 1):

You need to count and match the starting and ending using a counter. You need to do something like:

1. Check the total count. The counts of `(` should be equal to `)`.
2. The total count should be an even number.
3. We'll have two counters.

   1. The real count is the true sum of the `(` as `+1` and `)` as `-1`.
   2. The normal count is the current sum (legal) of `(` and `)` but it doesn't go less than `0`.
   3. Only when both the counts are `0`, the parentheses are valid.

**Use Case** and why I use two counts:

```
))((
```

For the above case, the count will be: `+2`, while the `realCount` will be `0`. So this gets invalidated. **This way, it not only checks the count of the brackets but also the semantics of it.** Hence the two counts.

**Code**

```js
function validParentheses(parens) {
  var count = 0,
      realCount = 0;
  parens.split("").forEach(function(v) {
    if (v == "(") {
      count++;
      realCount++;
    } else if (v == ")") {
      count--;
      realCount--;
    }
    if (count < 0)
      count = 0;
  });
  return (count === 0 && realCount === 0);
}

console.log(validParentheses("(())"));
console.log(validParentheses("()()"));
console.log(validParentheses("))(("));
```

**Clever Method**

I could also give another clever method:

```js
function validParentheses(parens) {
  var indent = 0;
  // Go through the parentheses and do for each.
  // Keep checking the conditions on the way.
  for (var i = 0; i < parens.length && indent >= 0; i++) {
    indent += (parens[i] == '(') ? 1 : -1;
  }
  // If it's 0, then good.
  return (indent == 0);
}

console.log(validParentheses("(())"));
console.log(validParentheses("()()"));
console.log(validParentheses("))(("));
```

Comment: Why use `map` if you're not using the result? And surely the counters thing is more complicated than needed? Just increment on opening and decrement on closing. If the result isn't 0, they're not matched.

Comment: Yep just use `.forEach(function(v)`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Real Count is the true value of the `(` and `)` as `+1` and `-1`.

Comment: @GarrettKadillak Updated with `.forEach` boss... `:D`

Comment: @PraveenKumar hello i didnot understand this line...can you write in simpler way indent +=

Comment: @texirv Sorry, which line you told? First or second code?

Comment: @texirv Nopes. Not right. That answer doesn't work if you give: `())(()`! `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Yes it does. She has a `counter < 0` check in there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Eeeks... I tried it and it says brackets matched. Not sure! `:(`

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the string adding to a counter when you see `(` and removing from it when you see `)`. If the result isn't `0`, they're not matched:

```js
function check(str) {
  var open = 0;
  for (var n = 0; n < str.length; ++n) {
    var ch = str[n];
    if (ch === '(') {
      ++open;
    } else if (ch === ')' && --open < 0) {
      return false; // Got ) with no corresponding (
    }
  }
  return open === 0;
}
function test(str) {
  console.log(str, check(str));
}
test("((()()()))");
test("((()");
test("()))");
test(")())");
test("()");
test("x");
```

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Fair point, should probably fail immediately if `)` when `open == 0`. Done.

Comment: I also added a cleverer method. Check it out... `:D`

Comment: @texirv: Melannie's code is just the above, but with the `open < 0` check moved (and an undeclared variable).

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Your "clever" method is just my answer above, but assuming the string doesn't contain anything but `(` and `)`, and moving the `open < 0` check into the `for` condition.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hello can you help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600110/minimise-the-code-since-i-am-using-the-same-code-only-the-content-in-p-tags-chan

Answer (score 0):

Approach using `String.prototype.match()` to create array. Would work if other characters also in string

`shift()` and `splice()` remove pairings until none left or a mismatch found

```js
function isMatching(str) {
  // create array of only parentheses
  var braces = str.match(/\(|\)/g);
  // must at least have pairs, but even if they aren't matches will be caught below
  var hasPairs = braces.length %2 === 0;

  while (braces.length && hasPairs) {
    // close can't precede open.
    // a close is removed removed from array when open is found
    // so at any point in this loop if first element in array is `)` it is a mismatch
    if (braces.shift() === ')') break;

    // we have an open, look for first close
    var closeIdx = braces.indexOf(')');

    // if no close for this open, get out of here
    if (closeIdx === -1) break;

    //or remove matching close
    braces.splice(closeIdx, 1);
  }
  // combination of `shift()` and `splice()` above will remove each pair
  //  any break above would leave elements in array due to mismatch
  return !braces.length;
}

logMatch("(()")
logMatch("((()()()))")
logMatch("(())");
logMatch("()()");
logMatch(")(()");

function logMatch(str){
   console.log(str, isMatching(str))
}
```

I'm late to the party but this is a good exercise

Comment: @texirv don't think so since it doesn't consider cases like `)()(`

Answer (score -2):

```
var bracketString = "((()()()))";
var counter=0;

for (i = 0; i < bracketString.length; i++) {

    if (bracketString[i] === "(") {
        counter++;
    } else if (bracketString[i] === ")" ) {
        counter --;
    } 
    if (counter < 0){
        console.log('Brackets mismatched'); // for example ())(
        break;
    }
}

if (counter==0){
   console.log('Brackets matched');
}

else if (counter>0){
   console.log('Brackets mismatched');
}
/* we don't consider counter<0 because before getting out of the for it passes 
this validation. */
```

Comment: In the case ')()(' it would entre the if (counter <0), write to the console brackets mismatched and break.

Comment: @Praveen can you update in this code...I can understand this code...since its so simple